# Direction of electrons (current) in car circuit

Tags: batteries, automotive

I read this somewhere.

> Electrons flow from negative to positive. This is called electron flow. Originally it was believed they flowed from positive to negative. This was later found to be incorrect and we call this conventional current.

Can someone explain how current flows from car battery to e.g car radio (and other things) and return back to battery ?

Why is the negative terminal of battery connected to the chassis/car body?

Why it is advised to always remove negative terminal first when removing the battery?

Comment: Current flow of electrons is a "electro-chemical" process ...

Comment: Generally, the lower potential is connected to "ground" because you can touch it. However, in some type of applications, it may be the "highest" potential that is grounded for "security reasons". Where you can touch, ground it.

Comment: https://mechanicbase.com/electric/how-to-disconnect-a-car-battery-in-a-safe-way/

Comment: these are three different questions, and all of them already have multiple answers on this site.

Comment: "Why it is advised to always remove negative terminal first when removing battery ?" This has absolutely nothing to do with the direction in which electrons move. It is because the negative terminal equals chassis. If you remove the positive terminal first then accidentally bump into something with it, you can cause a short across the battery with the chassis acting as conductor.

Comment: Car grounding techniques would fill a whole term of university lessons!

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is the "conventional current flow". It says the current flows from a high potential to a low potential (i.e. from plus to minus). Now remember that current was discovered long before the electron. So the convention stuck. For any practical purpose in e.e. you just use the conventional current flow.

Why is negative terminal of battery is connected to chassis/car body?
It is an industry standard (after WWII) deriving from the practicalities of electronics (whether you need positive or negative voltages).

Why it is advised to always remove negative terminal first when removing battery ?
If leave the negative to the chassis there are many non-isolated points to short-circuit the positive. Removing the negative is much safer.

Answer (score 1):

Too many questions that are not really related, but I'll try.

---

The "direction" of the electric current is a matter of convention.

It was standardized as the direction of a virtual positive charge carrires, long before the discovery of the electron.

That's why electrons travel in the direction opposite to the "current".

The "current" outside the battery flows from the positive to the negative terminal, electrons travel from the negative to the positive terminal.

(The "outside of the battery" part is important - inside the battery everything is the other way round)

---

!!! Edit:
No, the directions of electron drift and the current are not the same. The current (as used in calculations of electric circuits) is the direction of travel of IMAGINARY positive charge carriers. If the REAL charge carriers are negative, they happily travel in the opposite direction.

For analyzing an electric circuit, it doesn't matter if the real carrires are positive or negative. It is up to them to move in a proper way.

What matters is the direction of the current. You may find quite a few cases when the conductor has both positive and negative carriers (as in electrolytes, then they travel in the opposite directions) or only positive carriers (as in P-type semiconductors).

As for your metaphor about the "excess" of electrons - they are in excess at the negative battery terminal. They repell each other (as they carry the same charge) and they use every possibility to jump to the positive terminal.

(The excess of electrons is exactly that - a metaphor. So is the moving of the electrons - I wrote "drift" for a reason. It looks way too early for a young person like you to imagine what a real electron party with beer and cigarettes looks like...)

---

In cars, the chasis is used as a negative conductor. Historically, it was positive (randomly choosen and standardized). It was later found that the positive potential promotes corrosion and from 1960s on cars (as well as boats, machinees and pretty much everything else that is DC-powered) are negative-chasis.

---

Why disconnect the negative terminal in the car?

1. See the corrosion point above. You don't want to mess with the problem-prone connection at the positive terminal. It is usually harder to undo as well.
2. The car may have sources of electricity other than the battery. It may be the capacitors of various electronic devices in the car.

Shorting them by touching the positive wire to an exposed metal parts will make the current flow backwards and may blow something. This is a common failure mode of the voltage regulators that are part of almost any electronics.

On the other hand, it is not possible to short anything by touching the negative wire to a part that is connected to the negative wire in the first place.

Comment: @fraxinus- Thank you for answer. I did not understand when you said that the "current" outside the battery flows from the positive to the negative terminal, electrons travel from the negative to the positive terminal. 
Isn't the direction of current same as direction of electrons ?   At positive terminal of battery there will be build up of excess electrons with potential energy (which creates voltage). If so, electrons would like to get away from positive terminal (higher potential) and move towards negative terminal(lower potential) through circuit creating what we call current.

Comment: Answer edited and (hopefully) improved. You may read the new part.

Answer (score 1):

> "Electrons flow from Negative to Positive. This is called Electron flow.

Correct but don't worry about it. The convention is that current flows from positive to negative.

> Originally it was believed they flowed from Positive to Negative.

Not quite. Since there was no knowledge of electrons there was no belief that they flowed one way or another.

> Can someone explain how current flows from car battery to e.g car radio (and other things) and return back to battery ?

It's the same as any other circuit. In the case of a car half the wiring can be eliminated by using the chassis as the return 'wire'.

---

> Why is negative terminal of battery is connected to chassis/car body?

@fraxinus has explained well that this is due to convention and minimising corrosion.

---

> Why it is advised to always remove negative terminal first when removing battery ?

[image]

*Figure 1. Here an uninsulated spanner is being used to work on the battery + terminal. If any other part of the spanner touches any grounded part of the vehicle while the battery - lead is still attached a major short will occur. Disconnecting the negative first eliminates this risk. Image source: [Mechanicbase](https://mechanicbase.com/electric/how-to-disconnect-a-car-battery-in-a-safe-way/).*

Comment: Thank you @Transistor. So it is just out of caution we remove negative first. I assume if I make sure that positive terminal doesn't touch body of car then It will be safe to remove that first as well. Am I right ?

Comment: If you used insulated tools then maybe. It will be saf**er** to remove the negative first. If the spanned touches the chassis while removing the negative then nothing happens.

Comment: Sure I will remove negative first. I was just asking for my understanding.